# highstock crosshair width according to zoom

Tags: highcharts, candlestick-chart

I have a highstock chart witch `candlestick` data type.
When I mouseover the data point, I want to highlight the background of the point.
This is what tooltip -> crosshairs do:

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: true
}
```

But the only width option to set is the fixed width. See http://jsfiddle.net/8YBd7/.
This fixed width works with initial zoom, but when I change the zoom, the width is not updated with new point width.

When I set 100% width, the crosshair would fill entire chart area:

```
tooltip: {
    crosshairs: {
        width: '100%'
    }
}
```

Is there another option how to highlight current data point by changing its background or setting the width to the pointPixelInterval or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, I produced a dirty workaround, so improvements are welcomed:

```
    xAxis: {
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function() {
                    this.chart.tooltip.crosshairs = [];
                    this.chart.options.tooltip.crosshairs.width = (this.width / (this.series[0].points.length-1));
                }
            }
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QbdEu/1/

Whenever the zoom is changed, the width is recounted according to chart width and number of displayed data points. The width is not updated when calling `redraw()`, so the old crosshair needs to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `Renderer` http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Renderer.rect() which allows to plot any shapes and defined width? Only what you need is getting point width in pixels frpm(chart.series[0].data[0].graphic) and then setting correct widht of "shape".

Comment: Crosshair is special with the onmouseover functionality. With `Renderer` I would have to use mouseover and mouseout callbacks...

Comment: You can create object like var = chart.renderer.text()... then in mouseover event destroy() or add() object.

Comment: Given that this is not the intended use of the crosshair feature, I'm afraid any solution you come up with is going to be a bit dirty...your current solution is pretty clean under the circumstances